# Django: Product attributes and custom fields form in product page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I just start to learn Django and I want to create a Product model with attributes, custom fields and custom field options. Custom field options exemple:
Line 1: [YOUR TEXT] | Custom field options: [FONT] [FONT SIZE] [...]
Line 2: [YOUR TEXT] | Custom field options: [FONT] [FONT SIZE] [...]

So I've created this models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    active = models.BooleanField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductMeta(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField('Product')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    def upload_path(self, filename):
        return 'static/uploads/images/%s%s' % (timezone.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d/%Y%m%d_'), filename)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    default = models.BooleanField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductCharacteristic(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name="characteristics")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('ProductAttributeCategory')
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', related_name="attributes")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ordering = ['-category']
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s : %s' % (self.category, self.name)

class ProductAttributeCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductAttributeValue(models.Model):
    attribute = models.ForeignKey('ProductAttribute', related_name="values")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductCustomField(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name="custom_fields")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductCustomFieldOption(models.Model):
    fields = models.ManyToManyField('ProductCustomField', related_name="options")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductCustomFieldOptionValue(models.Model):
    option = models.ForeignKey('ProductCustomFieldOption', related_name="values")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

But now I don't know how to create the form in product details page in which the user can choose the product attributes (color, size...) and the product custom fields (and custom fields options). I've tried a lot of things but no results.

Can you help me please? :)

Answer (score 1):

your question is unclear to me and your even more confusing. However see this if it helps

In your models.py

```
from django.db import models
from model_utils import Choices

colour_choices = ('Blue', 'Green')


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        reuturn self.name


class ProductAttributes(models.Model):
    product = models.Foreignkey(Product, related_name='products')
    colour = models.CharField(choices=Choices(*colour_choices))
```

In your forms.py
    from django import forms
    from .models import Product, ProductAttributes

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Product


class ProdductAttributesForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductAttributes
```

Write your views.py, urls.py and template accordingly 
this method will give you a text box to enter products and drop-down for choosing color.
Hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what I want. I want a thing like this:
`class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['attributes']`
But 'attributes' is only defined in ProductAttribute model by "related_name" property, so it's not work.

Comment: why not render two separate forms you may use some ajax or javascript to get your'Product' details filled first then the 'ProductAttributes'

Comment: I thought Django had a function to do what I want. But Yes I can use multiple forms.